# some crontab job not working , not all

Tags: scripts, python, cron

I have a python job need to run every day

It need start_date and end_date parameters, so I use date .

The command didn't work at first, but no problem when executed in shell:

```
0 7 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/income_revenue.py $(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d') $(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')
```

After some searching I found I need escape `%` in crontab . New version still didn't trigger

```
0 7 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/income_revenue.py $(date -d '-1 day' '+\%Y-\%m-\%d') $(date -d '-1 day' '+\%Y-\%m-\%d')
```

So I created a shell script with content

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/income_revenue.py $(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d') $(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')
```

And added in crontab :

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/job.sh
```

Still not trigger.  Though `/bin/sh /home/ubuntu/job.sh` worked in shell.

I also tested below:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo $(date -d '-1 day' '+\%Y-\%m-\%d') >> /tmp/crontab.log
```

It worked.

I can't understand why !

Comment: Debug the python program by sending its output to a log file: `/home/ubuntu/job.sh > /home/ubuntu/pythonjob.log 2>&1`. This writes both STDOUT and STDERR to the log file specified, so you can see what goes wrong.

Comment: @Jos  No problem while run in shell,  it just not running , no output.